# Using a "playlist" table to drive ordering for other tablers

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a slightly complex database setup. Here is the schema and what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
Content
    ContentID int not null primary key
    SectionID int not null
        foreign key on Section.SectionID
    ContentData varchar(MAX)

Section
    SectionID int not null primary key
    SectionTitle varchar(255)

Playlist
    PlaylistPosition int not null primary key
    ContentID int not null
        foreign key on Content.ContentID
```

Content:

```
    ContentID  SectionID  ContentData
    ---------  ---------  -----------
    0          1          Content #1
    1          1          Content #2
    2          1          Content #4
    3          1          Content #3
    4          0          Stuff #2
    5          0          Stuff #1
    6          2          Things #3
    7          3          Misc #2
    8          2          Things #1
    9          2          Things #2
    10         3          Misc #1
```

Section:

```
    SectionID  SectionTitle
    ---------  ------------
    0          Stuff
    1          Content
    2          Things
    3          Misc
```

Playlist:

```
    PlaylistPosition  ContentID
    ----------------  ---------
    10                5
    20                4
    30                0
    40                1
    50                3
    60                2
    70                8
    80                9
    90                6
    100               10
    110               7
```

Desired output from query:

```
    SectionID  SectionTitle  FirstPlaylistPosition  FirstContentID
    ---------  ------------  ---------------------  --------------
    1          Stuff         10                     5
    0          Content       30                     0
    2          Things        70                     8
    3          Misc          100                    10
```

I want the above query to be presented in a view so that it can be queried as a pseudo-table.

**The goal is to get a list of all of the sections, and to get both the first position in the playlist of the first item matching that section, and the ID of that item in the content table.** Note that sections, content IDs, etc. may be completely out of order. The defining order is the playlist table itself.

This was my first attempt using a subquery:

```
SELECT Section.SectionID,
    Section.SectionTitle, 
    MIN(Playlist.PlaylistPosition) AS firstPlaylistPosition,
    (SELECT ContentID
        FROM Playlist 
        WHERE dbo.Playlist.PlaylistPosition = MIN(Playlist.PlaylistPosition)
    ) AS firstContent
FROM Section
INNER JOIN
    Content
    ON Content.ContentID=Section.SectionID
INNER JOIN
    Playlist
    ON Playlist.ContentID = Content.ContentID
GROUP BY Section.SectionID, Section.SectionTitle
ORDER BY firstPlaylistPosition
```

This throws the error:

```
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
```

I tried to back off a bit and at least get the proper correct first **playlist** position:

```
SELECT Section.SectionID,
    Section.SectionTitle, 
    MIN(Playlist.PlaylistPosition) AS firstPlaylistPosition
FROM Section
INNER JOIN
    Content
    ON Content.ContentID = Section.SectionID
INNER JOIN
    Playlist
    ON Playlist.ContentID = Content.ContentID
GROUP BY Section.SectionID, Section.SectionTitle
ORDER BY firstPlaylistPosition
```

This does not give the correct results:

```
SectionID  SectionTitle  FirstPlaylistPosition
---------  ------------  ---------------------
0          Content       30
1          Stuff         40
3          Misc          50
2          Things        60
```

Flipping the Join and the original select produces exactly the same results:

```
SELECT Section.SectionID,
    Section.SectionTitle, 
    MIN(Playlist.PlaylistPosition) AS firstPlaylistPosition
FROM Playlist
INNER JOIN
    Content
    ON Playlist.ContentID = Content.ContentID
INNER JOIN
    Section
    ON Content.ContentID = Section.SectionID
GROUP BY Section.SectionID, Section.SectionTitle
ORDER BY firstPlaylistPosition
```

I really only have to group on section title:

```
SELECT Section.SectionID,
    Section.SectionTitle, 
    MIN(Playlist.PlaylistPosition) AS firstPlaylistPosition
FROM Playlist
INNER JOIN
    Content
    ON Playlist.ContentID = Content.ContentID
INNER JOIN
    Section
    ON Content.ContentID = Section.SectionID
GROUP BY Section.SectionID
ORDER BY firstPlaylistPosition
```

but that gives

```
Column 'Section.SectionTitle' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: Your desired output has some typos I believe.  Also, you should consider paring down your question a bit as it is very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
select SectionID, SectionTitle, PlaylistPosition, ContentID
from (
    select 
        p.*, c.ContentData, s.SectionID, s.SectionTitle, 
        row_number() over (partition by s.SectionID order by p.PlaylistPosition) as rn
    from Playlist p
    join Content c on c.ContentID=p.ContentID
    join Section s on s.SectionID=c.SectionID
) x 
where x.rn = 1
order by PlaylistPosition
```

Output:

```
SectionID   SectionTitle    PlaylistPosition    ContentID
0           Stuff           10                  5
1           Content         30                  0
2           Things          70                  8
3           Misc            100                 10
```

Explanation: The inner query just scans `Playlist`, joining to the related tables. Then we add a `row_number()` column that counts the *nth* row per section.

Then we wrap it in an outer query and filter down to only the 1st row per section, using the `row_number()` column.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Sorta forgot about the OVER and PARTITION BY clause (I studied them in college...lol)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select A.*, PL.ContentId as FirstContentId
from (
select S.sectionId, S.SectionTitle, 
min(P.PlaylistPosition) as FirstPlaylistPosition
from Section S inner join Content C on S.SectionId = C.SectionId
inner join Playlist P on C.ContentId = P.ContentId
group by S.SectionId, S.SectionTitle ) A 
inner join Playlist PL on A.FirstPlaylistPosition = PL.PlaylistPosition
```

The query is self-explanatory. I'm getting the minimum PlaylistPosition for each section through the associated ContentId. Then I'm getting the associated ContentId for that record.

You can add an order by at the end of the query to order it in any particular order.

Results:

```
SectionId   SectionTitle                                       FirstPlaylistPosition FirstContentId
----------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------- --------------
0           Stuff                                              10                    5
1           Content                                            30                    0
2           Things                                             70                    8
3           Music                                              100                   10
```